# Use grep or awk to extract formatted dates from a text file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file with many dates, written as "January 1, 2014". How can I exact all of these dates from a file in chronological order (they are ordered in the file) using awk or grep?

I basically want:
grep "$a %d, %d" file.txt
But, I want to let $a = {January, ... , December}.

Basically, in the end, I want a file that has:

```
June 1, 2010
June 5, 2010
...
```

Comment: Does each line have *only* dates? Please provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: Everytime something of the form "Month xx, xxx" appears, I would like to extract it. Often it appears as nowrap;">January 15, 2013</span ... etc so they are not always separated strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only 12 month names, it is not unreasonable to hardcode them into the expression. Remember I am using `...` below but **you should write in the actual month names.**

```
 egrep -o  '(January|February|March|...|December) [0-9]+, [0-9]+' Input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!What does the -o do?

Comment: @Cokes, It makes it so that only the matching part is output instead of the whole line.

Comment: So the + after [0-9] just means an integer of any length, and just [0-9] would mean any integer from 0 to 9?

Answer (score 1):

### TL:DR

```
$ sort -M /tmp/dates | awk -v month=June '$0 ~ month {print $1, $2, $3}'
```

### Use GNU Sort and GNU Awk

GNU sort provides the `--month-sort` flag. Given the following input:

```
December 31, 2014
June 5, 2010
December 31, 2013
June 1, 2010
January 1, 2009
```

the sort command will sort the lines into a reasonable date-sorted order. If you have to do a secondary sort, you can always do that, too.

Meanwhile, you can then use the awk command to match each line against the desired month (stored in the *month* variable) and then print just the date fields from each matching record.

On my system, given the input above, I get the following output when `month=June`:

```
June 1, 2010
June 5, 2010
```

Comment: OP mentioned that his file already has the dates ordered. You are solving a different problem.